# Left margin of Margin: auto-ed elements = to padding left of 100%-width overflow item

Tags: html, css

Let me demonstrate the problem with the following HTML:

```
<section style="text-align: center;">
  <header style="margin: 0px auto; width: 300px; background: orange;">&nbsp;</header>
  <div>
    <article style="overflow-x: auto; width: 100%; background: pink;">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/10000/10" />
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

The '`article`' element in there; I'd like the `IMG` element in there to be the same distance from the left of the page as the `header` element. I want this to be true regardless of how wide the user resizes their browser.

And I want to do it with CSS only.  *You can add new elements, but not within the '`article`' tag.*

I imagine this to be impossible, if not difficult.  I had a few ideas, but could you help?

Comment: you mean center the article so it's the same position as the header? if you put the same styles on the containing div as the header then they will be the same positions http://jsfiddle.net/fWDCp/1/

Comment: I've added an extra section to my answer, where I explain how this can be done for every modern browser, as opposed to my original answer that just included the answer for certain browsers that support `calc()`. You might want to see if this was what you're looking for.

Comment: @Huangism ; sorry to mention this-- that isn't an option.  100%-width overflow item is in the title because this div has to actually be displayed as a 100% width div.  Limiting the overflow/scroll area isn't an option.

Comment: @SoreThumb the title of this question is quite confusing to what it means. The answer by Joey seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `calc()` method

This can be done with the (experimental) `calc` property:

```
div article {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 300px/2);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rKTD4/)

Here you'd have to enter the width of the `<header>` (in this case `300px`) and it will automatically determine what `50% - (width) / 2` is. This won't automatically change if you change the style for the `<header>` though, and [it is not supported in too many browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc).

### `margin-left` and `left` method

This is a method that would work in every modern browser: defining a `left` positioning, and then a negative left `margin`:

```
div article {
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rKTD4/1/)

This first moves the element to 50% width on the page, and then moves it 150px to the left via its negative margin. You will have to enter the width of the `<header>`, like the `calc()` method, but here you'll have to divide it by 2 yourself (shouldn't be too hard :P)

Comment: luckily, I don't need to worry about mobile browsers RE: the calc answer!